# method filling array with Jsoup not waiting for jsoup to complete website request

Tags: java, android, multithreading, jsoup

So I have a method that is designed to use JSOUP to grab a specified web page then filter it down to the values I need then write those to an array and then in a second part of the method that array is read from and everything but a few specific characters in each entry is split off and whats left is saved to a second array. Code below:

```
public void updateHrrrLabels() {
    hrrrLabels = new String[24];
    final LinkedList<String> rawHours = new LinkedList<>();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
// Method to get Hrrr model times as an array of Strings. Code based on example from Medium.com:https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-parse-html-pages-on-android-with-jsoup-2a9b0da0096f
        public void run() {
            final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://mag.ncep.noaa.gov/model-guidance-model-parameter.php?group=Model%20Guidance&model=HRRR&area=CONUS&ps=model").get();

                Elements links = doc.select("tr");
                int superi = 0;
                for (int i = 22; i < 26; i++) {
                    Element link = links.get(i);
                    Elements lin = link.select("td");
                    Element time;

                    for (int j = 0; j < lin.size(); j++) {
                        time = lin.get(j);
                        rawHours.add(time.text());
                        builder.append(time.text() + "\n");

                    }
                    superi++;


                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                builder.append("Error :      ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
            }


        }
    }).start();
    for (int i = rawHours.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        hrrrLabels[23 - i] = rawHours.get(i);
    }
    String[] SplitTime;
    hrrrTimes = new String[hrrrLabels.length];
    Log.d("rewtimes", "length=" + hrrrLabels.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < hrrrLabels.length; i++) {
        Log.d("rewtimes", "i=" + i + " :" + hrrrTimes[i]);
        SplitTime = hrrrLabels[i].split(" ");
        hrrrTimes[i] = SplitTime[1].substring(0, 2);
    }
}
```

The problem I am getting is that whenever I run the method it crashes when it gets to:

```
SplitTime = hrrrLabels[i].split(" ");
```

and throws a null pointer exception. This appears to be due to the fact that when running the code, the method does not wait for the `Jsoup.connect().get()` to finish loading the page into doc. Thus .Split() is performed on a null string ref and voila null pointer exception.

I confirmed this because whenever I run through the method with the debugger line by line it runs fine since that request has time to complete. I have tried using methods like `android.os.SystemClock.sleep()` in various spots to try and allow the request time to sleep but I sense that is both ineffective and improper use of that method (since that sleeps everything right?).

What do I do to ensure that the code waits until the Jsoup get has completed (and ideally no longer than that)?

Comment: Use AsyncTask to asure that you finish loading the page before processing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jsoup.connect().get()` is a synchronous call, so when it returns it will have connected and retrieved the response. The issue in your code - which you have correctly identifed as being somehow related to 'waiting for something to finish' - is because you invoke `Jsoup.connect().get()` inside a separate thread and then you do not wait for that thread to complete before attempting to use what Jsoup returns.

At this line:

```
.start()
```

You are starting the thread which invokes Jsoup and then you immediately continue  - on the main thead - with this ...

```
for (int i = rawHours.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    hrrrLabels[23 - i] = rawHours.get(i);
}
```

... which uses variables which it expects to have been populated within that separate thread. So, before the 'Jsoup thread' has completed its work you try to use variables which the 'Jsoup thread' has not yet populated.

The simplest fix here is to `join` the 'Jsoup thread' thereby forcing your main thread to wait until the Jsoup call has completed before trying to use the state which the 'Jsoup thread' is responsible for populating. For example:

```
...
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    ...
});
t.start();

// wait for the 'Jsoup thread' to complete before continuing
t.join();

for (int i = rawHours.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    hrrrLabels[23 - i] = rawHours.get(i);
}
...
```

But, since you have to wait for the Jsoup call to finish there seems little point in running that in a separate thread at all so your code could be simplified to:

```
hrrrLabels = new String[24];
final LinkedList<String> rawHours = new LinkedList<>();
final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

try {
    Document doc =
            Jsoup.connect("http://mag.ncep.noaa.gov/model-guidance-model-parameter.php?group=Model%20Guidance&model=HRRR&area=CONUS&ps=model").get();

    Elements links = doc.select("tr");
    int superi = 0;
    for (int i = 22; i < 26; i++) {
        Element link = links.get(i);
        Elements lin = link.select("td");
        Element time;

        for (int j = 0; j < lin.size(); j++) {
            time = lin.get(j);
            rawHours.add(time.text());
            builder.append(time.text() + "\n");

        }
        superi++;
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    builder.append("Error :      ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
}

for (int i = rawHours.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    hrrrLabels[23 - i] = rawHours.get(i);
}
String[] SplitTime;
String[] hrrrTimes = new String[hrrrLabels.length];
System.out.println("rewtimes, length=" + hrrrLabels.length);
for (int i = 0; i < hrrrLabels.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("rewtimes, i=" + i + " :" + hrrrTimes[i]);
    SplitTime = hrrrLabels[i].split(" ");
    hrrrTimes[i] = SplitTime[1].substring(0, 2);
}
```

Comment: Well since this is being called as a part of a larger android application I do need to have it run in a separate thread since android mandates that networking tasks should not be run in the main thread to avoid impairing performance of the main thread and the UI. As a secondary solution building off of your second suggestion couldn't I put everything in the method into the body of the runnable? I put some stuff outside/after it as I didn't fully understand the difference.

Comment: I think the key point is that your current code runs partly on one thread ('the Jsoup call) and partly on the main thread (using the response from the JSoup call) and since the second part relies on the first you may aswell have both parts on the same thread. If you'd rather that not be on the main thread then you could put it all inside a separate thread (e.g. what you described as "put everything in the method into the body of the runnable") but you cannot split the work across two threads without forcing one thread to wait on the other.